# Address of const char* is what data type?

Tags: c, gcc, types

I have the following code:

```
const char* names = {"apples", "oranges", "grapes"};
```

What data type is `&name[0]` ?  GCC is complaining.  It isn't const char** because GCC is complaining about this:

```
const char** address_of_first_name = &name[0];

"note: expected 'const char ** ' but argument is of type 'char **' "
```

Is it const `char * const`  or what?  Headache in progress ...

What data type is `&name[0]` ?  I'd hate to fix this compiler error incorrectly.

Comment: For the sake of consistency: Is your variable named `names` or `name`?

Comment: @B. Nadolson: `const char* names = {"apples", "oranges", "grapes"};` is already non-compilable, quite meaningless and severely affects the meaning of the question. I suspect that this is not a real declaration, since the error message you get is not possible with this declaration. Please, post real code.

Comment: @jogojapan You're right, I didn't think well.

Comment: I tried to simplify the code example.  I'm thinking this is unsalvagable and I better submit a different question.  I think my code simplification is fatally flawed.  Sorry.  The real code involves a function and a preprocessor defined array that is not easy to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make your `names` an array of pointers `const char* names[]` and initialize them as you did, then you can do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   const char* names[] = {"apples", "oranges", "grapes"};

   const char* first = names[0];
   const char* second = names[1];
   const char* third = names[2];

   const char* foo = &(*names[0]);

   printf("%s", foo);
   printf("%s", second);
   printf("%s", third);

}
```

[Live Example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/jQJvy%2419)

If you want the address you can do this:

```
 const char* addr = &(*names[0]); //print addr gets "apples"
 const char** add = &names[0]; //print add gets 0x7fff14531990
```

Comment: I've edited my question to better explain what I'm after.  I phrased the question poorly, I'm trying to figure out the data type accessing the ADDRESS of the first element (i.e. doing &(const char*) is what data type? )

Comment: @B.Nadolson I have added what you are looking for to my answer.

Comment: -1 Please answer in the same programming language as used in the question.

Comment: @Lundin I have changed it to be entirely C.

Comment: Despite botching the question a bit with an invalid oversimplification, I have discovered I'm not crazy and have found the issue.  Sorry.  A pointer to a const char* is a const char** like logic dictates, it is the real code that is way wrong.  Sorry all.

Answer (score 4):

Correctly, your array should look like

```
const char* names[] = {"apples", "oranges", "grapes"}; // array of pointer to char
```

Now, when you apply

```
name[0];
```

this returns the address to the first element. ("apples")

And instead of

```
const char** first_name = &name[0];
```

try

```
const char* first_name = name[0];
```

So you get the first string in your array.

Comment: Now you made everything even more confusing.

Comment: @PerJohansson Well, this is `C`, after all^^ Hooray to pointers!

Comment: I meant that your answer is wrong and unhelpful. First line is right, but not the rest.

Comment: I give myself an F for the example.  I don't want the string, I want the address of the first element.  I should have called it something other than first name.  Major question phrasing fail on my part.

Comment: In this case, `&name[0]` has the type `const char **` and it's the address of the first element of the array, not of the string literal

Answer (score 2):

The question is flawed since the

```
const char* names = {"apples", "oranges", "grapes"};
```

initializes the `const char*` scalar as if it were an array.

Comment: I botched the example pretty bad.  Sorry.